# mmenu doesnt fire onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, mmenu

I am using the mmenu jquery plugin (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/).
When clicking on items on the menu it doesnt trigger my onclick event. Any ideas why this could be happening would be much appreciated.

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span id="showScanDataBtn">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-leaf"></i> Scan Data
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span id="showPickingBtn">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-list"></i> View Picking
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span id="logoutBtn">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the javascript:

```
$(function () {
$("#showPickingBtn").click(function (e) {
        alert("Button Clicked!");
    });
});
```

I have also tried the exact same but with a tags instead just in case the span was causing the issue, but im having the same effect.

Comment: Did you try to load your JS when the doc is ready ? `$(document).ready(function() {}`

Comment: Yes the JS is loading on document.ready $(function(){... is shorthand for the same thing ($( document ).ready(function() {...)

Comment: seems to work fine in a fiddle. Did your browser gif some other javascript error in the console?

Comment: @caramba noted, i will make sure i take on your advice. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

try with `...on('click', function...`

```js
$(function () {
$("#showPickingBtn").on('click', function (e) {
        alert("Button Clicked!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span id="showScanDataBtn">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-leaf"></i> Scan Data
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span id="showPickingBtn">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-list"></i> View Picking
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span id="logoutBtn">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Maybe you can use this as example so you just have to set the onclick event once and then inside check for id and do whatever you want with it...

```js
$(function () {
  $("#menu").find('li span').on('click', function (e) {
    if(  $(this).attr('id') === 'showPickingBtn' ) {
        alert('CRAZY - ' + 'showPickingBtn' + ' has been clicked');
      } else {
        alert($(this).attr('id') + ' has been clicked');
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span id="showScanDataBtn">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-leaf"></i> Scan Data
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span id="showPickingBtn">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-list"></i> View Picking
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span id="logoutBtn">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, changing to the ..on('click', function (e) {.. event has definetly helped but its still not behaving as expected after a few show/hides of the different panels. Could it possibly be because the panels are originally hidden when page first loads?

Comment: @ErikaDanis yes the .on('click' also works if elements are hidden or get loaded later via ajax. if you have another question with show/hides which do not work as expected you have to post a new question showing the relevant bits of code, there is no way to respond that without knowing more about what your code does and what you really want..

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$("#showPickingBtn").on("click", function (e) {
    alert("Button Clicked!");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment it was really useful!! Ive now changed to ..on("click", function(e)){... as you suggested, and it does work for a little while. However i think it may have to do with the fact im showing and hidding panels within my onclick event. When it stops working, if i refresh the page it kicks in again for a while until after a few show/hides it stops again...

Comment: @ErikaDanis It does sound like some other code could be colliding with this. However, I'd have no way of knowing that or what! All I can suggest is to post some more code or to look in your console for specific errors when it stops working.

Comment: After more testing even a standard <a href="#" id="showPickingBtn">Show Picking</a> within the body of one of my panels doesnt trigger the onclick event. Maybe it has something to do with the fact they are originally hidden when my page first loads?

Answer (score 0):

this code working for me

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#showPickingBtn").click(function (e) {
                alert("Button Clicked!");
            });
       });
```